# Xamarin Visual Studio 2019 can't recognize Xiaomi 9t pro

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2019

i'm trying to use Xamarin with my Xiaomi 9t Pro but even though all my drivers are up to date and i enabled "USB debugging" and "install via USB", VS 2019 doesn't show my phone as an accessible device. It doesn't show at all in fact as if it wasn't plugged for VS.

thx,

Comment: does adb recognize it?  If not this is a device/driver issue and nothing to do with VS

Comment: i don't know how to see if adb recognize it. I can just see the phone on windows

Comment: Check the link below to set up your device for Development. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/set-up-device-for-development

Comment: ADB reconize the phone. We tried with 2 different phones and with Bluestack 4. ADB reconize each of them but VS don't reconize the phone